# Data is not getting inserted in pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to create a pysaprk dataframe manually.
But data is not getting inserted in the dataframe.
the code is as follow :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('PySpark DataFrame From RDD').getOrCreate()

column = ["language","users_count"]
data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
print(type(rdd))
sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=column)
print(sparkDF)
```

output:
DataFrame[language: string, users_count: string]

dataframe should get inserted with data

Comment: if you want to print df content in console use .show on your dataframe

Comment: but data is not getting populated in this dataframe that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing the dataframe you created. Forget the `rdd`.

```
>>> column = ["language","users_count"]
>>> data = [("Java", "20000"), ("Python", "100000"), ("Scala", "3000")]
>>> sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=column)

>>> 
>>> sparkDF.show()
+--------+-----------+                                                          
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

issue was with import
we need to import as follow :

```
import os
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```